# Is "max(a,b)" missing from Android NDK

Tags: android

There appears to be no `max()` function in the Android SDK (API level 8).
Am i mistaken?

Requirement:

```
r = max(0, r-1);
```

I'm reluctant to use the ternary operator because it's time-critical
and I can't be sure the compiler will use registers appropriately
(to avoid recalculating r-1).

Comment: I really don't get it. You mentioned NDK in the title but in your question you talk about SDK. Can you explain?

Comment: Hi Macarse, this is C code, not Java.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but in NDK-r7b I was able to compile max by changing it to MAX. Hope this helps somebody-

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write `if (r < 1) r = 0; else r -= 1;`? That performs about as few operations as necessary.

If you have atomicity requirements, I suppose one would have to think a bit harder and use temporaries.

Comment: Thank you Kerrek, an elegant solution. Not sure it helps with more complicated a's and b's, i.e expressions, but a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Math package.

Try:

```
r = Math.max(0, r-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in C, why not just use a macro:

#define MAX(a,b)   (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

r = MAX(0,r-1);

it's probably there anyway (it's in gcc)

Comment: Hi Brian, because I'm concerned that if b is an expression it will be evaluated twice.